# How to force Docker to use a specific commit hash of an image?

Tags: git, docker, yaml, wsl-2

I am having trouble getting Docker to use a specific commit hash of an image. I want to use the image with SHA1 hash 1e0561c5cb6eba1e379f4c91648a2df8297059cc, but when I run the command "docker compose --profile auto up --build", the latest version is used instead. The Docker Compose YAML file is included in the question.

I have tried specifying the image with the full hash in the Docker Compose file, but it still pulls the latest version. Is there a way to force Docker to use the specific commit hash I want? Any help would be appreciated.

For reference, the image in question is located on this GitHub repository: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui

Comment: where is the docker-compse file?

Answer (score 3):

In order to pull a docker image with its own SHA you have to follow the below syntax

shell command

```
docker pull ubuntu@sha256:26c68657ccce2cb0a31b330cb0be2b5e108d467f641c62e13ab40cbec258c68d
```

docker compose example

```
services:
  web:
    image: ubuntu@sha256:26c68657ccce2cb0a31b330cb0be2b5e108d467f641c62e13ab40cbec258c68d
```

Example of official Nginx image where you can get the full sha [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/nginx/stable-alpine3.17-slim/images/sha256-991a3950a672b7d2729474f060feb0a0d08223a124e67bbcb9a4aa516006f278?context=explore)

Official Documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

You can force Docker to use a specific image with following syntax:

```
NAME:[TAG@DIGEST]
```

If this doesnt work you should give us more information.